# Port scanning by internet provider

Tags: connection, internet

I have received a message from my internet provider that I am abusing the internet connection.
The moment when they scanned my connection, it was connected to the internet: surveillance cameras, smart doorbell and the house alarm.

I should be very grateful if someone could explain to me what does it mean the logs below (beside the timestamp, I don't understand anything).

Thank you very much for your help.

Time stamps are in NTP-synced Unix seconds, time zone UTC (GMT, +0000);

```
2022-10-09T03:34:20+02:00 188.27.116.219.56222 > 91.190.98.85.81: Flags [S], seq 3740817335, win 0, options [mss 1452], length 0
2022-10-08T15:25:07+02:00 188.27.116.219.41568 > 91.190.98.59.9530: Flags [S], seq 3715184853, win 0, options [mss 1452], length 0
2022-10-08T01:21:03+02:00 188.27.116.219.37135 > 91.190.98.83.81: Flags [S], seq 694423715, win 0, options [mss 1452], length 0
2022-10-07T01:01:08+02:00 188.27.116.219.54629 > 91.190.98.162.9530: Flags [S], seq 597634110, win 0, options [mss 1452], length 0
```

Comment: Ask them back how exactly you were abusing (i.e. what's *their* definition of abusing).

Comment: In these logs, which address is yours – is it the one on the left (188.27.116.219)?

Comment: If you are on `188.27.116.219`, then it would seem you are running some form of mass scan and the sample given is just that, a sample. I suggest you run wireshark on your interfaces and see what is going across them. If it is coming from your standard DSL router, then ensure it has the latest recent firmware.

Comment: Do you host services on ports 81 or 9530? it seems like they are trying to indicate that you have services on those ports that they could connect to. its possible that you have UPNP enabled on your router and one or more of your smart devices, and the device is opening up the port. either way, try to get more clarity from them on what is allowed, and what they think you are doing that you shouldn't be.

Comment: @FrankThomas, "host services"? I have no idea I have a smart doorbell that sends me notifications on my phone, every time when somebody passes in front of my door. Do you think that this could cause issues?

Comment: @TomYan, their abuse definition is: Generating unusually high traffic with the purpose or effect of overloading a server's or an Internet user's connection, or exhausting server resources or blocking access to legitimate users. This type of abuse defined is referred to as "flood".

Comment: @TomYan another abuse: Any activity with the purpose or effect of accessing, obtaining, and/or modifying information/resources that are not public. These types of activities include, but are not limited to: exploiting security holes in any computer connected to the Internet, searching for security holes in any computer connected to the Internet, and using "proxy" services without the consent of the owner of these services.

Comment: Sounds like you are being used to perform DDoS attack.

Comment: indeed. it is not uncommon for devices like IP cameras and doorbells (and insecure routers) to be enlisted in botnets used for DDOS attacks.